# Python - Selenium - Openpyxl : I have problem with openpyxl after create drop list excel

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, openpyxl

**Hello Guys, I have Excel and the excel has two sheets , sheet1 and sheet2.**

**I use sheet1 in my script, and sheet1 create drop list excel get value from sheet2.**

```
import openpyxl

path = r"C:\Users\John\Desktop\test.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
    sheet = wb['sheet1']
    language = sheet["A2"].value
```

**Sheet1 :**

[image]

**Sheet2 :**

[image]

**Everything work fine but I see this Error in Result :**

```
C:\Python\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py:300: UserWarning: Data Validation extension is not supported and will be removed
  warn(msg)
```

**How can I fix it without remove the get value from sheet2.**

Comment: if below i not the answer to your question , share few more details

Answer (score 0):

though your code works fine for me , an the message you have mentioned i the warning message, may come by few reasons, 1 - you have manually deleted the data then use clear all function to clear cells 2 - if you have change the file extension manually , check if below lines can resolve your issue, also check if sheet1 is Sheet1  ..

```
import openpyxl

path ='test.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path, read_only=True, data_only=True)
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
language = sheet['A2'].value
print(language)
```

Comment: This not what I mean, I have two sheets in one Excel, the first sheet name 'sheet1' has drop down from the another sheet name 'sheet2' in some Excel

Comment: so what you want to do with these 1.. share more details please

Comment: I run selenium script by ['sheet1'] , and script run fine , but I see this message error : C:\Python\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py:300: UserWarning: Data Validation extension is not supported and will be removed
  warn(msg)